# Package adding on device

Tags: android

How i can detect package adding on device using service and after it get package name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Broadcast with ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED action . So that when a new package will be added in your device you can do your work onReceive() method of Broadcast.